# XNA Hold and Click on same object

Tags: c#, xna, mouse

If the same object in a game have two different actions for clicking on it and holding the mouse clicked over it, using the default input (the current and the last MouseState), you will activate the click action even with you are holding. For example, you use the hold to drag n' drop an object over the screen, but when you click it, it should vanish. On the moment you just click on the object to move it, it'll vanish, which is an unwanted result.

```
MouseState current, last;

public void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
   current = Mouse.GetState();

   bool clicked = current.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && last.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released;
   bool holding = current.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed;

   if(clicked) vanishObject();
   if(holding) moveObject(current.X, current.Y);

   last = current;
}
```

I thought to solve it using a flag to "held more than N seconds" and put the vanish on ReleasedClick, checking  the flag, but changing the event time doesn't seem to be an elegant solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for everyone that answered me, but no one changed the fact to achieve the click on the Release event, and not on Press.

Answer (score 0):

You should just change your logic for vanishing the object. What you're really wanting is

```
if (clicked && !holding) vanishObject();
```

That should be the simplest way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about clicking the wrong way. The easiest way to implement this behavior is to only trigger the Clicked action if the mouseState was Pressed last frame and Released this frame, and if a certain time has not been achieved. In code:

```
private const float HOLD_TIMESPAN = .5f; //must hold down mouse for 1/2 sec to activate hold
MouseState current, last;
private float holdTimer;

public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    bool isHeld, isClicked; //start off with some flags, both false
    last = current; //store previous frame's mouse state
    current = Mouse.GetState(); //store this frame's mouse state
    if (current.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        holdTimer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds();
    }
    if (holdTimer > HOLD_TIMESPAN)
        isHeld = true;
    if (current.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        if (isHeld) //if we're releasing a held button
        {
            holdTimer = 0f; //reset the hold timer
            isHeld = false;
            OnHoldRelease(); //do anything you need to do when a held button is released
        }
        else if (last.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) //if NOT held (i.e. we have not elapsed enough time for it to be a held button) and just released this frame
        {
            //this is a click
            isClicked = true;
        }
     }
     if (isClicked) VanishObject();
     else if (isHeld) MoveObject(current.X, current.Y);
 }
```

Of course there is room for some optimization of this code but I think it's sensible enough.

Comment: I think its better to check for the mouse Position, if the realease was at the same position as the click, it was clicked, else it was dragged

Answer (score 0):

```
   const float DragTimeLapsus = 0.2f;

   if (current.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released) time = 0;
   else time+= ElapsedSeconds;

   bool clicked = current.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released
               && last.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed 
               && time<DragTimeLapsus;
   bool holding = current.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed 
               && last.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed 
               && time>DragTimeLapsus ;
```